# Company wide parent pom

Tags: java, maven

Is it possible that I use a `mvn deploy` for a single parent pom? This pom.xml file will be the parent pom of all my projects. Is it possible for me to deploy just this pom.xml file and no other artifact?

If i use this as my company wide pom, do i have to include the module tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>onestopspot</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>OneStopSpot - Parent</name>
    <description>Android application for OneStopspot</description>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>confiz-repo</id>
            <url>http://10.10.10.230:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
     </distributionManagement>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.3</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <sdk>
                            <platform>10</platform>
                        </sdk>
                        <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                    </configuration>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <module>api_library</module>
        <module>instrumentation</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in fact this is a standard practice to reduce the amount of boilerplate in project POMs.

For more information on parent POMs: https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-relationships.html#pom-relationships-sect-project-inheritance

And for using POM-only projects to keep boilerplate out of project POMs: https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure it's possible. Just define your packaging as pom and it will work.

Be aware of groupId and version inheritance. If you don't want to inherit this like in a multimodule project you just have to override it.

Here is an example:

Company wide parent pom:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.mycompany.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>


</project>
```

Multimodule project parent pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>de.mycompany.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>my-overridden-groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-overridden-artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>myOtherModule</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

After that you can go one and make modules with the pom parent above

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do that, it's a common practice. The `packaging` type should be set to `pom` in this case:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

A project with type `pom` does not require a `src` or `test` directory, just the plain pom file is enough.

I recommend that you use the *Maven Release Plugin* to release and deploy the parent pom file: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/

Comment: The parent pom file usually doesn't include any modules, it's just the pom file. Don't confuse the parent pom file with the root pom of a multi-module project, they don't have to be the same. Especially not when you're trying to create company-wide parent pom.