# Maven parent-child relationship

Tags: java, maven

I have encountered the below "**pattern**" for maven parent-child relationships:
[image: Relation ship example]http://yuml.me/3f8dd366

In this example we have a module with 2 sub modules. The module has a parent pom "Parent for building the Module" which knows the two sub-modules as it's children.

The sub-modules how ever have no idea that this parent knows them, and they think their parent is the one named "Parent for dependency management". Which has common configurations like dependency management, plugin configuration, common properties etc.

**My question:**
Is this a "good" pattern? Meaning does it have advantages/disadvantages as the seemingly more intuitive patter of child<->parent relationship

Comment: where did you find this pattern? I am curious to discuss this approach in my team. Actually, I think the parent for building is kinda of strange, I think each module should know how to build itself and the project build should be the composition of the building of every single module, but speaking with more expert people and reading the source of this approach may change my mind!

Comment: Those arrows seem really confusing (the directions), and I don't think you're using "parent" consistently.  In fact I know that since Maven doesn't support multiple inheritance.  Please clear up what you mean by "parent."

Comment: @mardavi we have it in many projects at our company

Comment: @djechlin  as I already stated in comments below, one of the parents is indeed an aggregator

Comment: it may be good to separate the build pom from the real parent when you use Bamboo or Jenkins. In our company we have separate build configuration for each module, so we really do not want parent poms to trigger all the children's builds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One interesting thing to look at is the aggregator pom.

It's a pom that groups project by module, without having a "parent-child" relationship. The aggregator pom doesn't have dependencies management. It only manages the build.

Having both parent(s) pom and aggregator pom is quite a powerful feature of maven.

You can find more information [here](http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/maven-aggregator-vs-parent.html).

[This maven page](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#fig-maven-book) also has valuable insight on how to set up pom for complex projects.

Comment: In our team we set up our poms like that. Decoupling parent POM and aggregator POM prevent for instance to have to update parent pom of every modules each time you add a new module in the build lifecycle. In our case aggregator POM is only here to easily set up the build (in Jenkins) by configuring the multi-module project and not each submodule.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, after reading these pages I realized my terminology was incorrect

Comment: No problem. I think the confusion between parent pom and aggregator pom is quite common. Some people tend to use a parent pom when an aggregator should be used.

Answer (score 9):

Hum... I think I disagree with the terms on your picture. Here is how I see this:

[image]

This way of organizing modules can be confusing for lot of developpers, but it is a legal way of doing things.

Anyway, I don't recommend this approach because it's confusing. But sometimes, their is no alternatives.

**When using this configuration ?**

One (or more) of the *sub module* already have a parent (i.e. was developed in another project but you need to rebuild it). Note that the `<module>` entry in multi-module project is a relative path so you can have something like:

```
<modules>
    <module>../../somedir/othermodule</module>
    ...
</modules>
```

**When possible, I recommend to use the multi-module also as the parent** because:

- less confusing
- clean and readable `<modules>` and `<parent>` sections (no need to use ugly relative paths to specify the *parent* or the *submodules*)
- you can organize your modules in a clean hierarchical structure under SCM (so that maven-release-plugin will be happy) (I know that eclipse don't like hierarchical projects, but that's another problem)

Comment: Thank you,  my terminology was indeed mistaken. Can you please elaborate on when you would use this kind of configuration? Also, do you recommended setting the multi module project as the parent of the modules?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually good to have a company wide configuration pom which doesn't care about it's children and contains stuff like properties, dependecyManagement, repositories, pluginManagement etc. which all of them will inherit

Maybe this can help you: [Company wide parent pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499733/company-wide-parent-pom/)